# "Application pool 'XXXXXXXXXX' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool."

Tags: asp.net, wcf, application-pool

We have a ASP.NET/WCF app hosted in Window Server 2012 (IIS 7). We used the `basicHttpBinding`. This ASP.NET/WCF application exposes two methods; one is to receive messages and the other is to download a text file (1MB) onto the server.

On another server, we have ASP.NET hosted in Window Server 2012 (IIS 7) which is the client that consumes the exposed method mentioned earlier. This client application sends a message and uploads a text file at a high frequency. This communication between this ASP.NET/WCF application and client application works fine for a few hours until we get the following error at the ASP.NET/WCF side.

`Application pool 'XXXXXXXXXX' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.`

So, could you please shine some light regarding this issue that we are facing?

Comment: You'll probably not appreciate this, but it looks like your application pool is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool. It's a very clear error message.

Comment: I believe the way to fix this is to find out why your application is crashing and then address that issue. Since there is basically no information in your post indicating what is going on with your application, I'm afraid that it's really pretty hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: Yup, I understand the error message is clear but I want to know under what circumstances an application pool fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to something called "Rapid Fail Protection." When your underlying application crashes a certain number of times in a certain time period, the application pool is automatically disabled.

The default settings are 5 crashes in 5 minutes, but you can configure this yourself. [See this link for details.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787273(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply John. I will definitely try this. Another question, is WCF technology suitable to be used in an application that accepts high number of request ?

Comment: I think so. I'm sure there are tradeoffs with other technologies, but within reason I think it should be fine. [Check out this link to see how performance can vary.](http://blog.shutupandcode.net/?p=1085)